# IE Automation with an array

Tags: arrays, excel, ie-automation

Hello I work as a parts analyst for my company. I search engine serial numbers on our online catalog to see if the required information is present on the website for customers. I have about three thousand numbers to check each month. I have an excel sheet that I copy the engine serial number from and paste it into the search of the online catalog. Its a very tedious task. I have been working on a macro to automate this process. I have an array in the macro. I want the array to skip serial numbers that don't need to be search. So far the macro will open the browser to the e-catalog and loop through the array highlighting all the serial numbers that contain the values in the array. I now need the array to skip those values. i would like to use an if statement with the array so that each time I run the macro it will run faster because the volume of values being searched is decreasing.

Scenario

1. I click a button in excel it opens the required file and begins to search the serial numbers in column A.
2. If F2 = Y then skip searching for A2 in the catalog, however if F2 = N then search A2
3. If the search for A2 returns the required information then enter Y in F2, else enter N in F2, go to A3 and repeat process.

I have searched many forums and i have not been able to find a solution. The macro I have is below. I need help to complete the macro. I tried to get the array to skip the values in the array and highlight all the others by adding Not to the if statement. That did not work, instead all serial numbers were highlighted when I added "Not" to the if statement. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
Sub HighlightValue()

Dim MyVals As Variant
MyVals = Array("*472908*", "*471905*", "*471914*", "*471935*", "*471917*", "*471920*", "*471933*", "*471932*", "*471934*") 'Enter all the values to search for

 Application.Goto Range("A2"), False
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        For Each esn In Selection
            For i = LBound(MyVals) To UBound(MyVals)
                If esn.Value Like MyVals(i) Then
                esn.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'yellow
            Exit For
        End If
        Next i
        Next esn
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
```

End Sub

[image]

Comment: Is it your intention to highlight all cells in column A, if the first n characters of the cell (I guess n = 6) are not matched by a value in myVals? (Your code already highlights any cells whose first 6 characters match an element in the array - the array however, contains no values that match any of the cells in the range [A2..A17] - I just added "471907*" to the array myVals and had cells [A13..A17] highlighted) Updating your question by removing irrelevant code irrelevant would make things more clear. - e.g any reference to IE, folders and files :)

Comment: Yes I wanted to highlight all cells that did not match the array, as a test for my end goal. My end goal is to skip any cell that does match the array and check the ones that do not match the array. The values in the array are serial numbers that will not have the ATS (column F) information that I am seeking. Sorry for not posting a section that contained the values in the array. This data sample is from a list of 30k+ entries. When I run the macro to highlight the array values it runs perfectly. The next stage is to get the macro to use the array to check the website for the ATS.

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Here's a quick test I whipped up.
There's 2 approaches I would choose from.

1. Set them all to yellow and clear the colour if the entry is found in
   the array
2. Use a flag in the loop. Set it to false before-hand, then set it to true if the entry is found in the array. After the for-loop, use the state of this flag to  decide whether or not to colour the cell.

I've used approach #2.

Also note that based on the data you've presented, the wildcard (*) at the start of each string in the array is unnecessary. (I also added the last element in the array, so I'd have some cells that matched and some that didn't)

```
Sub highlightCellsNotInArray(myVals)
    Dim found As Boolean

    Application.Goto Range("a2"), False

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

        For Each engSerNum In Selection
            found = False

            For i = LBound(myVals) To UBound(myVals)
                If engSerNum.Value Like myVals(i) Then
                    found = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i

            If found = False Then
                engSerNum.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ' yellow
            End If
        Next engSerNum

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim arrayVals
    arrayVals = Array("472908*", "471905*", "471914*", "471935*", "471917*", "471920*", "471933*", "471932*", "471934*", "471907*")
    highlightCellsNotInArray (arrayVals)
End Sub
```

Comment: The code runs great. Now I would like to use it to automate a search in IE and enter Y in column F of the serial number being searched if the information exists. If the information does not exist. move to next serial with an N in column F. Also to only search serial numbers with N in column F but skip all serial numbers that are in the array as they will always have an N in column F. I have some code but I am having trouble getting it to work.